# nightwatch select current element's inner div

Tags: nightwatch.js

i'm new to nightwatch and was wondering if there's any good way to select the inner element of a current element and then get the text? Assuming i have the following..and i'm trying to retrieve the text inside (a) tags of each (li).

so i would like to get 'text to retrieve' and 'text to retrieve 2'.

```
   ...
 <div class="mywrapperhere">
 <ul>
   <li>
     <a>.....
        <div>text to retrieve</div>
     </a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a>.....
        <div>text to retrieve 2</div>
     </a>
   </li>
   <li>...   
   ...
 </div>
```

I'm thinking along these lines..

```js
module.exports = {
  'Demo test 1' : function (browser) {
  ....
  
    
 //some sort of selector then gets from the anchor list
 ...'.mywrapperhere li a') : {
   ..
   //for each element of the anchor..
   {     
  //is there anyway to get it through something like 
          element.('div').innerHTML eg..
        //or am i forced to use browser.execute( ...getElementsByTag method
        //to achieve this?
  
  
   }
 }
   
    browser.end();
  }
};
```

Looking at the nightwatch api, i couldn't find anything allows me to do that. I'm particularly looking at the 'Element State' examples that doesn't seem to have a way for me to select the current element state's child element :

http://nightwatchjs.org/api/elementIdAttribute.html

The reason why i had to loop through the anchor tag level is because i'll need to retrieve a few more data besides the one from div tag, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `elementIdElement` and `elementIdText` to get text from a child element. First you can get all the `li` elements by using `.elements()`. Then you use `elementIdElement` to get a child element. Then you can use `elementIdText` to get the text of this child element. Here is an example that will allow you to get the text of both list items in your snippet and log the values to the console.

```
browser.elements('css selector', 'li', function(listItems) {
    listItems.value.forEach(function(listItem) {
        browser.elementIdElement(listItem.ELEMENT, 'css selector', 'a', function(anchor) {
            browser.elementIdText(anchor.ELEMENT, function(text) {
                console.log(text.value);
            });
        });
    }, browser); //have to pass in browser for scoping 
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i noticed that elementIdText will only get the value if it is visible to the user, if it is not then it will return empty string.

Comment: Ok. Is that an issue? You can use `.elementIdDisplayed` to check if the element is visible first if you need to.

Comment: but the value will return the value of  a tag But I want to text of a tag for e.g <a>a text <span>span text</span></a> value will return the following text "a text/span text"
have you some specific method to get only "a text"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to deal with that. As far as I know, there is no way to filter out the text from child elements.Only thing I can think of at the moment is to get the text of the child nodes and then remove it from the full text of the parent node. Then you should only be left with the text you are looking for.